# Getting values from childViewController before loading parentViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have a `viewController`(parentViewControleller) with a `view` (childViewController) object and a `button`.
The `childViewController` display google-Map. While the button redirects to other app passing values from the `childViewController` as parameters.

***childViewController***

[image]

So whenever I execute my code, the `parentViewController` executes first without fetching the values from the `childViewController` and finding the values as nil.

How am I suppose to execute `childViewController`,so that I can fetch the data and get it ready for `parentViewController` before the view gets displayed?

I tried calling childViewController's viewDidLoad() in parentViewController, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you are adding your `childViewController` through `segue` into your `parentViewController` then you should try accessing values in "prepareforSegue" method. If you are adding your child controller programmatically then you should access values after you add it to parent controller.

Comment: In general, you don't want to use view controllers as data storage objects.  You especially don't want to use them for storing **shared** data.  Create a shared model, write to it when things change, and read from it when you need to display things.

Comment: @PhillipMills My `childViewController` is generating co-ordinates on user click and the button fetches this values. So while loading the `parentViewController`, I need the `childViewController` to be executed and ready with the values. If you can certainly show an example for what you are suggesting will be more helpful.

Comment: It sounds like your `childViewController` (Which is actually a view, not a view controller) should be using a delegation pattern to call a function in te parent when it has new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get values from childViewController to parent in following manner:-

In your `childViewController` :-

```
var pvc = self.parent as! parentViewController
pvc.variable = yourValue //This will assign the value to variable.
pvc.function()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to load childViewController's view, before displaying it.  Just call

```
_ = childViewController.view
```

It will cause UIKit to instantiate view controller from XIB/Sotryboard, assign Outlets and call subsequent viewDidLoad/awakeFromNib functions.

Comment: Instance member 'view' cannot be used on type 'childViewController'

Comment: Hmm. So **childViewController** not a UIViewController then... Can you provide declaration of It please?

Comment: `parentViewController` is viewController in a storyboard and `childViewController` represents a rectangular region in which it draws and receives event as mention above image. So it doesn't need any explicit declaration.

Comment: OK, so in spite of the name, `childViewController` isn't actually a view controller...what is it?  What do you mean then by "execute `childViewController`" in your original question?

Comment: Image above represents part of Interface Builder.